# How to run one release at time on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I am to implement pre-deployment gates on my azure devops release.
I am using HTTP request gate to check each time if there is ongoing deployment.
The problem is, when deployment on one release finishes (stage 1 ), I want to prevent the deployment on next release in queue if there is (stage 2) to the pipeline that does not do deployment for example.

The end goal is, no matter how many releases in queue I have and no matter how many agents in my pool, I want to make sure that release start only if there is no other active release in deployment/other stages.

Comment: Please show your code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: i am using azure devops gates UI , no code envolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a gate of `Invoke REST API: GET` to call below [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#uri-parameters) rest api and check if there are any releases in deployment. See below steps:

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress&api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

1, Add a Invoke Rest Api Gate

Go to Pre-deployment conditions --> Enable Gate-->Add a Invoke Rest Api Gate-->Click Manage to create a service connection. See below screenshot.

[image]

2, Create a service connection shown in above screenshot.

When you Click **Manage** in above screenshot. You will be forward to **service connections** page. Click **new service connection** and select **Generic** type of service connection:

- The server Url: [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Proj}](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7BOrg%7D/%7BProj%7D)
- Password: [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

[image]

3, Go back to the Invoke Rest Api Gate. Select the service connection just created: See below

- Method: `Get`
- URL suffix and parameters: `/_apis/release/deployments?operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress&api-version=6.1-preview.2`
- Success criteria: `eq(root['value'][0], '')`

[image]

Above Invoke rest api gate will call the `deployments list` rest api to filter these releases that are inProgress or queued of deployment using `operationStatus` filter(ie. `operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress`). If the there is any deloyment is inProgress or queued the Success criteria: `eq(root['value'][0], '')` will failed.

If you using self-hosted agents and [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops). You can check the [Exclusive lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#exclusive-lock) on Environments and Agent pools.

Comment: i tried to do the same thing as the first solution. the problem with that appraoch is : i will explain with an example , if i have 1 active release and 1 pending release . at the active release i have 3 stages , when the first stage finish the deployment , for a few seconds before it continues to stage 2 , the status changes to queued , and at this time the pending release kicks off and start working because the GATE return value 0 since there is no status of inProgress for a few seconds . i am trying to do now more then 1 gate to handle this case also , i will update.

Comment: @VladiPikovski You donot need to add multiple gates. You can have a try using the filter parameter `operationStatus` instead of deploymentStatus. ie.   `operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress`. It retrieve the deployments that are queued or inProgress. I updated above answer.

Comment: that exactly what i did eventually , funny:) , thanks alot , with that method all works now.